# Chaining angularJS requests

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a simple example to follow where I use the response of a request to initiate additional GET requests.

I have 2 services - one returns a list of search results objects including an ID - a second which takes this ID and returns an image.

For example:

```
myApp.factory('Search', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/search/', {}, {
        getResults: {method:'POST'}
    });
}]);

myApp.factory('Image', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/image/', { id: '@id' }, {
        get: {method:'GET'}
    });
}]);
```

How can update my controller to use the output JSON of the first call to retrieve the images?

```
myApp.controller('myAppController', function($scope, Search, Image) {

    $scope.searchResults = Search.getResults();

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain promises (which is what resources is working on) by either nesting your calls or have the previous success method return a promise and then hatch onto that.

Depending on your scenario, this could be a simple solution:

```
Search.getResults(function (results) {
  var imageId = results[0].imageId; // don't know what you need
  $scope.images = Image.get({id: imageId});
});
```